# Repeating transcluded content in an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to write a simple tree directive in Angular which will nest items, and repeat the transcluded content declared in the first call to the directive, in each of the repeated items.

I have tried this,

```
angular.module('angularTree',[])
    .directive('tree',['$compile',function($compile)
    {

        return {

            scope:{item:"="},
            transclude:true,
            template:"<div class='tree-item'><ng-transclude></ng-transclude>" +
                        "<div id='tree-content' class='tree-content'>" +
                            "<div ng-repeat='child in item.items'>" +
                                "<tree item='child'><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></tree>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>",
            link:function(scope,element,attrs)
            {

            }
        }


    }]);
```

And it works up to a point. It creates a nested tree, with the transcluded content.

The problem is that the scope in the repeated child directives, is always pointing at the very first item declared. So when I have a variable like this in my controller..

```
var item = {name:John, items:[{name:Tony},{name:Jill}]};
```

And pass it into the directive like this

```
<tree item="item"></tree>
```

I get a nested list of items, but they all say 'John'.

I can see why this happens, because the second  is just going to have the same scope as the first..

My question is...how would I go about repeating the transcluded content in the child elements, but with the scope pointing to the child object not the top node?

I've read up on and tried using the $compile, and transclude functions, but I couldn't see any way to get this working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be work like you have it. I think you´ve just mixed up item and child. Can´t be sure on that since your code doesn´t show where it outputs the names.

Inside the ng-repeat loop, child refers to the given of item.items, but item still is the same as the outer item. I´ve provided a working example, with the outputs in the comments:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('tree',[function($compile) {
    return {
      scope:{
        item: "="
      },
      transclude:true,
      template: "{{item.name}}" + // John, Tony, Jill
                "<div class='tree-item'><ng-transclude></ng-transclude>" +
                  "<div id='tree-content' class='tree-content'>" +
                    "<div ng-repeat='child in item.items'>" +
                      "{{item.name}}" + // John, John
                      "{{child.name}}" + // Tony, Jill
                      "<tree item='child'><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></tree>" +
                    "</div>" +
                  "</div>",
      link: function(scope,element,attrs) {}
    }
  }]
)
.controller('treeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
    name: 'John', 
    items: [
      {name: 'Tony'},
      {name: 'Jill'}
    ]
  };
}])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the asker's problem, it would be preferable to explain how it works and what are the differences between it and what the asker has tried.

Comment: I did not change any of the important parts of the askers code, just added some examples, what would be outputted. Tried to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. You are right that the {{item.name}} works fine inside the ng-repeat. The problem is the content inside the second <ng-transclude>. In both <ng-transclude> elements, 'item' always points at the original item, not the child. I need a way to tell the second <ng-transclude> to bind itself to the child item, not the current item.

Comment: Could you maybe nearer explain what you want to achieve here? From what i understood, i think transclusion is not the right tool here.